# Still cannot connect through Internet even after PortMapping UPnP (Mono.Nat) with the Mirror framework

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, upnp, unity3d-mirror

Even after PortMapping (using Mono.Nat) connecting with the host's public IP address via [Mirror](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/) from one Network to other networks through the internet doesn't work. [Project File Download](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1McnChjMAZA_Qe9EMoR770Pg0iBbtzq36/view?usp=sharing)

UPnP **is enabled:**

[image: Router's UPnP settings, the game is literally listed there with both TCP and UDP]

I don't think the problem is inside the script because the port is already opened in the router settings. The script for PortMapping:

```
private void DeviceFound(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
{
    Debug.Log("1");
    INatDevice device = args.Device;
    Debug.Log("2");
    Mapping map = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 7777, 7777);
    Mapping map2 = new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, 7777, 7777);
    Debug.Log("3");
    device.CreatePortMap(map);
    device.CreatePortMap(map2);
    Debug.Log("4");
    int test = device.GetAllMappings().Length;
    Debug.Log(test);
    foreach (Mapping portMap in device.GetAllMappings())
    {
        Debug.Log("5");
        Debug.Log(portMap.ToString());
    }
}
private void DeviceLost(object sender, DeviceEventArgs args)
{
    INatDevice device = args.Device;
    Mapping map = new Mapping(Protocol.Tcp, 7777, 7777);
    Mapping map2 = new Mapping(Protocol.Udp, 7777, 7777);
    device.DeletePortMap(map);
    device.DeletePortMap(map2);

}
```

Edit:

- Added Mirror Documentations in the first paragraph. you can find about Tcp/Udp in "Transports".
- Added Project file download

Comment: Kindly please post the link to the Mirror framework documentation.

Comment: I tried setting up the initial phase from this [Mirror Documentation Page](https://mirror-networking.gitbook.io/docs/community-guides/quick-start-guide). I have covered till Part 7, and after that seems like I am able to play a multiplayer game without any issues or anything done to Router. This is the [output image](https://imgur.com/a/thwIXDR). Kindly note in this I am playing on the same computer. Do I have to try and play it on different computers on the same/different network?

Comment: It seems like I missed a crucial detail. I am trying to connect through **different networks**, basically through the internet. Both [routers](https://imgur.com/a/CpVgXrw)have UPnP enabled and have the port mapped, but are still unable to connect through the internet using the host's public IP address

Comment: Does KCP Transport have to do with the problem perhaps? are you using KCP or TCP for transport?

Comment: `NetworkManager` brought `KcpTransport` with itself. I'll try to somehow connect the game via different networks, but I might take some time to test the output for that setup, as I reach home.

Comment: I tried after changing my network [video depicting that](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HOgEgzDHxhJC4QvcRtRf251PR0tGSIwq/view?usp=sharing). It seems still it is working fine. I connected via mobile network in this video, and Unity is running on my laptop with my broadband connection, I forwarded the port [ScreenShot](https://imgur.com/a/RaZEM3V)

Comment: can you give me the project file you've made? I think reverse engineering would be easier

Comment: Please find the [link to the project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vTyOP0xEtJwtkVr6oyEYCoGvWA6OgDvH/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: I couldn't get your project working. I changed my original project to telepathy transport and still can't connect, both routers are UPnP enabled (I even manually added port forwarding). I haven't tried with one router and one mobile network, perhaps that's why your test works. I've added the Projects file download to the question. I'll test with one router and one mobile network tomorrow. Thanks for the help so far!

Comment: The connection to which you want to connect you have to forward the port on that not from which you are trying to connect. Moreover, it seems to be that you have to forward the port under [Virtual Server](https://www.cfos.de/en-gb/cfos-personal-net/port-forwarding/tp-link-tl-wr840n.htm) and not under uPNP.

Comment: I've tested it and it seems that: 
I've successfully connected between 2 different networks with one using a router and one using mobile network. and you don't need to port under Virtual Server and using UPnP works just fine.
**The problem** that's causing me to not connect between two routers was the **Firewall**. I've disabled my friend's router firewall and it worked flawlessly.

anyway, do you wanna post the answer? after all you're the one that helped me this far until my project actually works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both UPnP is enabled on both routers, what was missing was the **Firewall settings.**[image: firewall]I had to disable **Both of the firewalls** on the router settings to connect via the internet using the host's public IP address. ps. massive thanks to @nIcEcOw.